# Unit Of Work pattern (fflib library) and Attachment object

Tags: apex

Is there any way to use the fflib uow pattern to insert attachments and relate it to a parent sObject (in this case to an Event)? I am facing the following error due to the parentId is not an SObjectField.

```
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.name = 'myName';
    attachment.ContentType = 'plainText';
    attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf('Text');
    uow.registerNew(attachment,Attachment.ParentId,EventSF);
```

Error:

> Error:(414, 13) Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void registerNew(Attachment, Id, Event) from the type fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just shadowed the name of the standard object (`Attachment`) with your instance of it (`attachment`). Either rename it:

```
Attachment record = new Attachment();
SObjectField parentIdField = Attachment.ParentId;
```

Or if you don't want to change the name of your record instance, you need to use the fully qualified name to disambiguate:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
SObjectField parentIdField = Schema.Attachment.ParentId;
```